# Browser back button navigating to Bad request page in B2C while registering using Facebook identity provider

Tags: sitecore8, azure-ad-b2c

In a Sitecore integrated azure ad B2C application, while registering through Facebook, once the user is signed up in the application using a Facebook identity provider, the user is redirecting to the page where the user details are are displayed which are retrieved from the Facebook identity. But, the problem here is if the user refreshes the page or clicking on browser back button, then the "Bad request" screen is displaying.

The error message is showing like "{"status":"400","message":"Missing required element [Given Name]"}".

Answer (score 0):

When you press browser back button from any idp, an authentication failed response is sent to the b2c application.
Are you using Owin middleware? If yes, you need to catch the exception in your '**AuthenticationFailed**' event and handle it properly. Something like below.

```
if (notification.Exception.Message == "server_error")
{
   // the error message might be different based on the IDP, facebook returns server_error as reponse message                            
    notification.Response.Redirect("/");
}
```